# Error code: 16722 - Nested lock error in MongoDB MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am using MongoDB-2.6.1.

I tried `db.coll.mapreduce()` storing in `system.js` and accessing via `db.eval()`.

I faced the problem of **nested lock** (only for 100 documents) when running using `db.eval()`. But direct running of `mapreduce()` worked fine.

[image]
Snapshot of error message (nested lock).

**Is it not possible for storing `db.coll.mapreduce()` in `system.js` and accessing via `db.eval()` ??**
If not, what is the alternative way to this.

Could any one please help me out....

Comment: If you want to save map/reduce functions in system.js and execute it in the current shell scope, you should use `db.loadServerScripts()` first (which does a client-side eval into the current shell session). See: [Store a JavaScript Function on the Server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/). By default the [`db.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) command takes a global write lock which is going to interfere with your map/reduce .. *and* the Map/Reduce command already executes on the server so there is no need for db.eval.

Comment: yeahh correct.. MapReduce is one of the method for server-side operations. Is it not at all possible for storing mapreduce() in system.js and calling db.eval(). Why is that error??

Comment: First calling db.loadServerScripts() and then calling stored function myFunction() will work fine. We should not call using db.eval().

Comment: I saw you posted this question on the [mongodb-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/9jhHulYhT3Q) discussion group as well. If you have JS functions saved in system.js, they will automatically be eval'd & available in the server-side mapreduce() JS scope. In general the use of server-side JavaScript is discouraged as there are significant performance and scalability considerations.

Comment: So what is the right way to get the aggregated results on different fields (for example, say 6 fields). If we use aggregation, then the number of hits will be 6. I used mapreduce because I will have to hit database only once and get the aggregated results using some custom functions. What is the right way??